# Need to add promise method in a readFile method with help of bluebird plugin in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Requirement: Need to import bluebird plugin and include promisifyAll method in readFile method.

Below is the existing working code which doesn't have promise method.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.get( "/users", function(req,res) {
  fs.readFile("./users.json", "utf-8", function(err, data) {  

    if(err) {
      console.error("unable to read file");
    }
    else {
      try {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          res.send(data);
      }
      catch (e) {
          console.error("invalid json file");
      }
    }
  });
});
app.listen(8000,function(){
  console.log("listening on port 8000");
});
```

After running the above code, I am able to hit the URL with http://localhost:8000/users and get the  JSON value.

I imported blubird plugin and included promisifyAll method.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var Promise = require("bluebird");
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

app.get( '/users', function(req,res) {
  fs.readFile("./users.json", "utf8").then(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      console.error("unable to read file...");
    }
    else {
      try {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          res.send(data);
      }
      catch (e) {
          console.error("invalid json file");
      }
    }
  });
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

But I am getting "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received 'utf8'" for this above code. I don't understand why this readFile is not accepting "utf8".

Kindly help me to get this issue fixed at the earliest.

Comment: `fs` already exposes promises API, why do you need bluebird?

Comment: They expected to implement bluebird plugin in this exercise.

Comment: you have to add the callback function insede the 3th param or use readFileSync